# Vue.js data not available in created() function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm having issues with initialising my Vue component with data from localStorage. Here is a simplified version of my code

```
new Vue({
    el: "#my-element",
    created: () => {
        if (window.localStorage.getItem("verified")) {
            this.verification.verified = true;
        }
    },
    data: {
        verification: {
            verified: false
        }
    }
});
```

But I keep getting an error on the console `Cannot read property 'verification' of undefined`

If I put a `debugger` in the created() function, and I check the values of `this`, `this.verification` and `this.verification.verified`, they're all set to the values I have initialized with in the data object.

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Basically I'm trying to hide an element when the page loads if the user has already gone through the verified process at any previous time.

Answer (score 4):

The arrow function is intended for use when you want the value of `this` in the outer context to flow into your function body, rather than the function having its own context for `this`. This means that `this` in your `created` function does not point to your Vue instance.

You can however still use the shorthand method declaration syntax provided by ES6:

```
new Vue({
    created() {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured out the problem.. It's because I'm using ES2015 notation for functions.. Changing back to `function(){}` allows it to work again.. So I need to do some more research to figure out how to use ES2015 with Vue.js